# A mathematical approach to economics

Tags: reference-request, economics, online-resources, book-recommendation

Are there books or papers where economics is formalized and studied very rigorously? I am very interested in this topic. I would preferably like free online books and/or papers, but that is not necessary.

Comment: I guess you mean with statistics?

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? A lot of the more advanced stuff is very mathematical, just look at any book on macroeconomic or microeconomic theory...

Comment: I am looking for an axiomatic approach, not merely a computational one, to economics.

Comment: I still think that a lot of the macroeconomic and microeconomic theory books that are out there are what it sounds like you're asking for. I mean utility functions are mathematical functions, so a lot of what you do is mathematical in nature with interpretations that mean something in terms of economics. As long as you don't estimate models, there is no computational aspect to it either. I'm just saying it's hard to answer your question as economics is a quite mathematical subject to begin with.

Comment: @hejseb: Most micro or macro books out there do not use the *axiomatic approach*, which was popular in the hey-days of mathematical economics (think Debreu's: Theory of Value). The same is true of most books in applied mathematics: **naive** set theory is used instead of **axiomatic** set theory.

Comment: Standard graduate treatment of microeconomics is: Mas-Colell, Whinston, Green (1995): Microeconomic theory. If you are looking for very rigorous papers, check out articles in the Journal of Mathematical Economics (recent ones, the old ones (80s and prior) are on today's "normal" level).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful of what you wish for... Bernt Stigun's book "Towards a Formal Science of Economics: **The Axiomatic Method in Economics**" probably goes above and beyond of what you had in mind when asking for *rigor*. He starts with mathematical logic (first-order languages)...

[http://www.amazon.com/Toward-Formal-Science-Economics-Econometrics/dp/0262192845/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262192845)

Also I have a vague impression some research in "epistemic game theory" may use the axiomatic approach but I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Gerard Debreu's *Theory of Value* provides a mathematically rigorous analysis of the theory of general equilibrium in economics. It is considered a classic by many economists and won the author a Nobel Prize in Economics.

Here's the link to the pdf of the monograph: http://cowles.econ.yale.edu/P/cm/m17/m17-all.pdf.

Comment: Axiomatic yes, but it sometimes is hard to see it is economics.  Maybe start with a micro textbook such as Varian.

Comment: @Trurl Sure if we want to develop economic intuition, but if you are looking for an advanced microeconomic textbook with rigorous mathematics then I would recommend *Microeconomic Theory* textbook by Mas-Colell, Whinston, and Green.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [Economics for mathematicians](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052128614X) by Cassels. It is more focused on what mathematicians find interesting, rather than what economists find useful.

Answer (score 1):

Axiomatic Theory of Economics, 1999, by Victor Aguilar

This is a short 26-page simplified exposition written at the undergraduate level:

http://axiomaticeconomics.com/Axiomatic_Economics_Article_by_Aguilar.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Handbook of mathematical economics edited by Michael Intriligator, Kenneth Arrow.

In general, the Handbooks in Economics contains several interesting topics.

[Handbooks page](http://www.elsevier.com/books/book-series/handbooks-in-economics)