# Textbooks of economics for mathematicians

Tags: reference-request, economics

There was an [analogous discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/850260/727554) 6 years ago, but I open this discussion hoping there any some options on the market.
I'm looking after textbooks expecting mathematical maturity from the reader (or perhaps intended entirely for the mathematician), that follow a somewhat axiomatic approach and proceed as rigorously as possible in exposing the current state of economical sciences.
An alternative option for what I'm looking for is the current collection of problems of interests to the mathematicians, such as provided by [Economics for Mathematicians by J. W. Cassels](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052128614X)

Comment: The current state of economics is largely pseudo-science. Google Michael Hudson, and read Adam Smith.

Comment: I’m not an economist, neither i’m interested in such things, but some times ago a friend of mine warmly recommended Mas-Colell, Whinston & Green (1995) *Microeconomic Theory* and Acemoglu (2009) *Introduction to Modern Economic Growth*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but [Optimal Transport Methods in Economics](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691172767/optimal-transport-methods-in-economics) might be interesting.