# Is there any book "economics for mathematicians"?

Tags: statistics, book-recommendation, economics

If you search economics book there are plenty of them on the market. We may say the say about "mathematics for economists" or "application of mathematics in economics". But I've never seen book which tells me about economics based on statistics, optimization and other field of mathematics. Where every law, curve and so on is based on some statistical experiment or real analysis.

Example: I'm currently reading [https://www.amazon.com/Principles-Microeconomics-N-Gregory-Mankiw/dp/1305971493](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1305971493) and the problem here is that there're no proof for principles. Author just says "people always  have trade-offs". But from the other hand there's optimization theory, and if we care only about revenue function - we may find maximum. (So in that case we don't have any trade-offs).

Let me know, please, if you know any book "economics for mathematicians". Thanks!

PS. There's similar question on site, but it's outdated. (But have a little different idea) ([Textbooks of economics for mathematicians](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772773/textbooks-of-economics-for-mathematicians))

Comment: Could you please link to the similar question explicitly

Comment: Done, thanks for comment

Comment: That links to an even older https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850260/a-mathematical-approach-to-economics but the issue is that there are many "Mathematics for Economists" books but few "Economics for Mathematicians" books apart from J. W. Cassels's typewritten lecture notes, which were dated even in the 1980s when I took his course.

Comment: Economics is a very broad field.  Which topics in economics do you wish to learn?  A good graduate theory text in the subject should have sufficient rigor and proofs.

Answer (score 2):

Efe Ok, *Real Analysis with Economic Applications* provides an accessible introduction to aspects of real analysis that are important for economists. It's particularly strong on things to do with expected utility theory and optimization. It's quite a bit easier than standard graduate school texts covering real analysis. He also has a parallel work in progress on probability, available from his website.

Comment: That looks like another "Mathematics for Economists" book rather than an "Economics for Mathematicians" book

Comment: It sounds like what you might want is a graduate level economics textbook, perhaps like Varian or Kreps. That will have economics, but will rigorously develop the optimization etc behind the concepts.